# Draw Poly line in React Native On Image

Tags: android, image, react-native, draw, polyline

I was wondering how to draw a poly line in React native Platform

I am developing an application where i am capturing the picture and load it into `Image`

Though my question is how to allow user to draw the poly line on touch response  over to that `Image`

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: sorry  sir i did't try any thing to draw poly line because I stack on from where to start the poly line drawing